# How to reset JLabel foreground color?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jlabel, mouselistener

I have created a mouse move event to a `JLabel` to change its foreground color from white to black. My question is how to reset the label foreground color from black to white when mouse moved away from the label?

Comment: Please show the code that you wrote for the first half. See [mcve] for tips on how to write a good code example.

Comment: What have you tried so far?It is difficult to imagine where the issue lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you really want is a [`MouseListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) and monitor for the `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` events

See [How to use a mouse listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
public class Test extends JFrame{


    public Test(){

        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Hai");
        add(lbl);


        lbl.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                lbl.setForeground(Color.white);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                lbl.setForeground(Color.black);
            }

        });


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

hope it will help  for you.